# Solution for Check Balanced Parenthesis is not working correctly

Tags: c++, stack

I was solving a 'check balanced parenthesis' problem in which I was expected to output "Success" if the parenthesis' were placed in the right order, and if the parenthesis' were mismatched, I have to output the 1-based index of the unmatched parenthesis in the string.

Here's my source code for the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char get_pair_opening_bracket( char c );
int bracket_check( string &s );

char get_pair_opening_bracket( char c ){
    char o{};
    if( c==')' ){
        o= '(';
        return o;
    }
    else if( c=='}' ){
        o= '{';
        return o;
    }
    else if( c==']' ){
        o= '[';
        return o;
    }
}

int bracket_check(  string &s ){
    stack <char> brackets {};

    for( size_t i{}; i< s.size();++i ){
        if(( s[i]=='(') || ( s[i]== '[' ) || ( s[i]=='{' )){
            brackets.push(s.at(i));
        }
        else if(( s[i]==')') || ( s[i]== ']' ) || ( s[i]=='}' )){
            if( (brackets.empty()==true) || (brackets.top()!=get_pair_opening_bracket(s[i]) )){ 
                return (i+1) ; // problem here
            }
            else{
                brackets.pop();
            }
        
        }
    }
    if( brackets.empty()==true ){
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(){
    string s{};
    getline(cin,s);

    bool check{};
    check= bracket_check(s);

    if( check ==0 ){
        cout<<"Success"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<check<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have commented on the line where I feel the problem lies, which is causing the program to always output '1' in case of mismatched parenthesis. So, please help me with the bug .....

Comment: The code will be much easier to read if you get rid of redundant parentheses. For example, you can change `if(( s[i]=='(') || ( s[i]== '[' ) || ( s[i]=='{' ))` to `if (s[i]=='(' || s[i]== '[' || s[i]=='{')`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think the main problem is here

```
bool check{};
check= bracket_check(s);
```

You assign the integer return value to a boolean. So not surprisingly you only get 0 or 1 for an answer.

You have other problems, more instance what is your function going to return if the input is `"("`?

Incidentally I see this style quite a lot `size_t i{};`. What's wrong with `size_t i = 0;`? It's a lot easier to understand for an old-timer like me.

Comment: Yea, you are right , I too see the problems now, would update if I am able to fix them.

Comment: Regarding the use of size_t i{} , it is actually true initialization,  while i=0 is not initialization,  its more of assignment.  Its important because manier times, it may cause exceptions (mainly while using user defined classes)which might need extra attention.